# Submenu not displaying when bound to IsSubmenuOpen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem

I'm trying to show a SubMenu of items. Every time `IsSubmenuOpen` is set to true, I make a call in my view model to refresh the list that the MenuItem is bound to.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work illustrated here (even though Windows has 3 subitems):

[image]

View Model:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> CustomLayoutList { get; set; } 
public bool LayoutOptionsOpen { set { UpdateCustomLayoutList(); } }

private void UpdateCustomLayoutList()
{
    CustomLayoutList.Clear();

    var items = GetItems();
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        CustomLayoutList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Binding in Xaml:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding CustomLayoutList }" IsSubmenuOpen="{Binding LayoutOptionsOpen, Mode=OneWayToSource}"></MenuItem>
```

---

**EDIT:** Apparently on my computer this works fine. The list populates correctly and shows the SubMenu. For some other people, however, the SubMenu wouldn't open - despite verifying that the list has items in it.

To resolve this, I changed my solution to listen to the `SubMenuOpen` event, and in my xaml.cs code-behind I call `UpdateCustomLayoutList` directly. This works, but why did my initial solution not work, and is there a better way to solve this? Ultimately I would like to have zero code-behind.